# Why don't show image in front page

Tags: moodle

I'm building e-learning site by moodle. I add image as banner at Settings-> Site Administration 
-> Appearance -> Additional HTML.
It is shown after login but can't show before login.
Please, can anyone provide a suggestion to this?

Comment: Is there any option saying "Publish Site" or "Save changes" or "Make Live"? If there is, try using that. Or can you post here the addition HTML you have inserted?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! i clicked Save changes and appear current page but can't see from front page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings > Site Admin > Front page settings and tick "Include a topic section"

There are a number of other useful settings on that page, such as what users see before and after they log in.

You then need to add a Resource ("Label") in the Topic section on top.

Where do you want the banner to appear? Is it a site logo? Should it be in the header? Footer? Sidebar?

If it's a logo in the top left corner you're after, use a theme that supports logos such as Afterburner.

HTH,

ghee dough